# MongoDB count query very slow

Tags: mongodb, count, pymongo

In my MongoDB collection I have 28m documents.
The machine has 32GB of RAM and 100GB SSD. The machine is isolated to run only the MongoDB stuff (no other resource hoggers).

I have the following indexes in place:

```
producer.requestInTs  # regular (field type: Int64)
client.requestInTs  # regular (field type: Int64)
producer.requestInTs, client.requestInTs  # compound
```

I need to perform the following queries from my MongoDB:

```
# 17 million documents, ~5 sec
cursor = collection.find({"producer.requestInTs": {"$gte": start_time, "$lte": end_time}}).count()

# 23 million documents, ~7 sec
cursor = collection.find({"client.requestInTs": {"$gte": start_time, "$lte": end_time}}).count()

# 11 million documents, ~100 sec
cursor = collection.find({"producer.requestInTs": {"$gte": start_time, "$lte": end_time}, "client.requestInTs": {"$gte": start_time, "$lte": end_time}}).count()
```

Here is the output of `db.clean_data.getIndexes()` query:

```
[
{
    "v" : 2,
    "key" : {
        "_id" : 1
    },
    "name" : "_id_",
    "ns" : "query_db_test.clean_data"
},
{
    "v" : 2,
    "key" : {
        "producer.requestInTs" : 1,
        "client.requestInTs" : 1
    },
    "name" : "performance",
    "ns" : "query_db_test.clean_data"
},
{
    "v" : 2,
    "key" : {
        "client.requestInTs" : 1
    },
    "name" : "client.requestInTs_1",
    "ns" : "query_db_test.clean_data"
},
{
    "v" : 2,
    "key" : {
        "producer.requestInTs" : 1
    },
    "name" : "producer.requestInTs_1",
    "ns" : "query_db_test.clean_data"
}
]
```

Here's the output of the `explain` query:

```
{  
   'ok':1.0,
   'serverInfo':{  
      'port':27017,
      'gitVersion':'52e5b5fbaa3a2a5b1a217f5e647b5061817475f9',
      'version':'3.4.15',
      'host':''
   },
   'queryPlanner':{  
      'rejectedPlans':[  
         {  
            'inputStage':{  
               'direction':'forward',
               'multiKeyPaths':{  
                  'producer.requestInTs':[  

                  ]
               },
               'isMultiKey':False,
               'stage':'IXSCAN',
               'isSparse':False,
               'indexName':'producer.requestInTs_1',
               'isPartial':False,
               'indexBounds':{  
                  'producer.requestInTs':[  
                     '[0, 2527594134000]'
                  ]
               },
               'isUnique':False,
               'indexVersion':2,
               'keyPattern':{  
                  'producer.requestInTs':1
               }
            },
            'stage':'FETCH',
            'filter':{  
               '$and':[  
                  {  
                     'client.requestInTs':{  
                        '$lte':2527594134000
                     }
                  },
                  {  
                     'client.requestInTs':{  
                        '$gte':0
                     }
                  }
               ]
            }
         },
         {  
            'inputStage':{  
               'direction':'forward',
               'multiKeyPaths':{  
                  'producer.requestInTs':[  

                  ],
                  'client.requestInTs':[  

                  ]
               },
               'isMultiKey':False,
               'stage':'IXSCAN',
               'isSparse':False,
               'indexName':'performance',
               'isPartial':False,
               'indexBounds':{  
                  'producer.requestInTs':[  
                     '[0, 2527594134000]'
                  ],
                  'client.requestInTs':[  
                     '[0, 2527594134000]'
                  ]
               },
               'isUnique':False,
               'indexVersion':2,
               'keyPattern':{  
                  'producer.requestInTs':1,
                  'client.requestInTs':1
               }
            },
            'stage':'FETCH'
         }
      ],
      'plannerVersion':1,
      'winningPlan':{  
         'inputStage':{  
            'direction':'forward',
            'multiKeyPaths':{  
               'client.requestInTs':[  

               ]
            },
            'isMultiKey':False,
            'stage':'IXSCAN',
            'isSparse':False,
            'indexName':'client.requestInTs_1',
            'isPartial':False,
            'indexBounds':{  
               'client.requestInTs':[  
                  '[0, 2527594134000]'
               ]
            },
            'isUnique':False,
            'indexVersion':2,
            'keyPattern':{  
               'client.requestInTs':1
            }
         },
         'stage':'FETCH',
         'filter':{  
            '$and':[  
               {  
                  'producer.requestInTs':{  
                     '$lte':2527594134000
                  }
               },
               {  
                  'producer.requestInTs':{  
                     '$gte':0
                  }
               }
            ]
         }
      },
      'parsedQuery':{  
         '$and':[  
            {  
               'client.requestInTs':{  
                  '$lte':2527594134000
               }
            },
            {  
               'producer.requestInTs':{  
                  '$lte':2527594134000
               }
            },
            {  
               'client.requestInTs':{  
                  '$gte':0
               }
            },
            {  
               'producer.requestInTs':{  
                  '$gte':0
               }
            }
         ]
      },
      'namespace':'query_db_test.clean_data',
      'indexFilterSet':False
   },
   'executionStats':{  
      'nReturned':11712728,
      'executionSuccess':True,
      'totalKeysExamined':23086735,
      'allPlansExecution':[  
         {  
            'nReturned':73,
            'totalKeysExamined':111,
            'executionStages':{  
               'restoreState':2,
               'filter':{  
                  '$and':[  
                     {  
                        'client.requestInTs':{  
                           '$lte':2527594134000
                        }
                     },
                     {  
                        'client.requestInTs':{  
                           '$gte':0
                        }
                     }
                  ]
               },
               'inputStage':{  
                  'direction':'forward',
                  'restoreState':2,
                  'multiKeyPaths':{  
                     'producer.requestInTs':[  

                     ]
                  },
                  'needTime':0,
                  'indexBounds':{  
                     'producer.requestInTs':[  
                        '[0, 2527594134000]'
                     ]
                  },
                  'nReturned':111,
                  'dupsDropped':0,
                  'stage':'IXSCAN',
                  'seenInvalidated':0,
                  'needYield':0,
                  'invalidates':0,
                  'keyPattern':{  
                     'producer.requestInTs':1
                  },
                  'isPartial':False,
                  'isEOF':0,
                  'isSparse':False,
                  'indexVersion':2,
                  'indexName':'producer.requestInTs_1',
                  'isUnique':False,
                  'keysExamined':111,
                  'saveState':2,
                  'seeks':1,
                  'isMultiKey':False,
                  'works':111,
                  'dupsTested':0,
                  'advanced':111,
                  'executionTimeMillisEstimate':0
               },
               'needTime':38,
               'alreadyHasObj':0,
               'saveState':2,
               'nReturned':73,
               'docsExamined':111,
               'executionTimeMillisEstimate':0,
               'needYield':0,
               'works':111,
               'invalidates':0,
               'isEOF':0,
               'advanced':73,
               'stage':'FETCH'
            },
            'executionTimeMillisEstimate':0,
            'totalDocsExamined':111
         },
         {  
            'nReturned':73,
            'totalKeysExamined':111,
            'executionStages':{  
               'restoreState':2,
               'inputStage':{  
                  'direction':'forward',
                  'restoreState':2,
                  'multiKeyPaths':{  
                     'producer.requestInTs':[  

                     ],
                     'client.requestInTs':[  

                     ]
                  },
                  'needTime':38,
                  'indexBounds':{  
                     'producer.requestInTs':[  
                        '[0, 2527594134000]'
                     ],
                     'client.requestInTs':[  
                        '[0, 2527594134000]'
                     ]
                  },
                  'nReturned':73,
                  'dupsDropped':0,
                  'stage':'IXSCAN',
                  'seenInvalidated':0,
                  'needYield':0,
                  'invalidates':0,
                  'keyPattern':{  
                     'producer.requestInTs':1,
                     'client.requestInTs':1
                  },
                  'isPartial':False,
                  'isEOF':0,
                  'isSparse':False,
                  'indexVersion':2,
                  'indexName':'performance',
                  'isUnique':False,
                  'keysExamined':111,
                  'saveState':2,
                  'seeks':38,
                  'isMultiKey':False,
                  'works':111,
                  'dupsTested':0,
                  'advanced':73,
                  'executionTimeMillisEstimate':0
               },
               'needTime':38,
               'alreadyHasObj':0,
               'saveState':2,
               'nReturned':73,
               'docsExamined':73,
               'stage':'FETCH',
               'needYield':0,
               'works':111,
               'invalidates':0,
               'isEOF':0,
               'advanced':73,
               'executionTimeMillisEstimate':0
            },
            'executionTimeMillisEstimate':0,
            'totalDocsExamined':73
         },
         {  
            'nReturned':101,
            'totalKeysExamined':111,
            'executionStages':{  
               'restoreState':2,
               'filter':{  
                  '$and':[  
                     {  
                        'producer.requestInTs':{  
                           '$lte':2527594134000
                        }
                     },
                     {  
                        'producer.requestInTs':{  
                           '$gte':0
                        }
                     }
                  ]
               },
               'inputStage':{  
                  'direction':'forward',
                  'restoreState':2,
                  'multiKeyPaths':{  
                     'client.requestInTs':[  

                     ]
                  },
                  'needTime':0,
                  'indexBounds':{  
                     'client.requestInTs':[  
                        '[0, 2527594134000]'
                     ]
                  },
                  'nReturned':111,
                  'dupsDropped':0,
                  'stage':'IXSCAN',
                  'seenInvalidated':0,
                  'needYield':0,
                  'invalidates':0,
                  'keyPattern':{  
                     'client.requestInTs':1
                  },
                  'isPartial':False,
                  'isEOF':0,
                  'isSparse':False,
                  'indexVersion':2,
                  'indexName':'client.requestInTs_1',
                  'isUnique':False,
                  'keysExamined':111,
                  'saveState':2,
                  'seeks':1,
                  'isMultiKey':False,
                  'works':111,
                  'dupsTested':0,
                  'advanced':111,
                  'executionTimeMillisEstimate':0
               },
               'needTime':10,
               'alreadyHasObj':0,
               'saveState':2,
               'nReturned':101,
               'docsExamined':111,
               'executionTimeMillisEstimate':0,
               'needYield':0,
               'works':111,
               'invalidates':0,
               'isEOF':0,
               'advanced':101,
               'stage':'FETCH'
            },
            'executionTimeMillisEstimate':0,
            'totalDocsExamined':111
         }
      ],
      'executionStages':{  
         'restoreState':181031,
         'filter':{  
            '$and':[  
               {  
                  'producer.requestInTs':{  
                     '$lte':2527594134000
                  }
               },
               {  
                  'producer.requestInTs':{  
                     '$gte':0
                  }
               }
            ]
         },
         'inputStage':{  
            'direction':'forward',
            'restoreState':181031,
            'multiKeyPaths':{  
               'client.requestInTs':[  

               ]
            },
            'needTime':0,
            'indexBounds':{  
               'client.requestInTs':[  
                  '[0, 2527594134000]'
               ]
            },
            'nReturned':23086735,
            'dupsDropped':0,
            'stage':'IXSCAN',
            'seenInvalidated':0,
            'needYield':0,
            'invalidates':0,
            'keyPattern':{  
               'client.requestInTs':1
            },
            'isPartial':False,
            'isEOF':1,
            'isSparse':False,
            'indexVersion':2,
            'indexName':'client.requestInTs_1',
            'isUnique':False,
            'keysExamined':23086735,
            'saveState':181031,
            'seeks':1,
            'isMultiKey':False,
            'works':23086736,
            'dupsTested':0,
            'advanced':23086735,
            'executionTimeMillisEstimate':8609
         },
         'needTime':11374007,
         'alreadyHasObj':0,
         'saveState':181031,
         'nReturned':11712728,
         'docsExamined':23086735,
         'executionTimeMillisEstimate':98716,
         'needYield':0,
         'works':23086736,
         'invalidates':0,
         'isEOF':1,
         'advanced':11712728,
         'stage':'FETCH'
      },
      'executionTimeMillis':102699,
      'totalDocsExamined':23086735
   }
}
```

Here's the output for the `db.collection.stats()` query:

```
{
    "ns": "query_db_test.clean_data",
    "size": 56227937613,
    "count": 28302965,
    "avgObjSize": 1986,
    "storageSize": 16116736000,
    "capped": false,
    "wiredTiger": {
        "metadata": {
            "formatVersion": 1
        },
        "creationString": "access_pattern_hint=none,allocation_size=4KB,app_metadata=(formatVersion=1),block_allocation=best,block_compressor=snappy,cache_resident=false,checksum=on,colgroups=,collator=,columns=,dictionary=0,encryption=(keyid=,name=),exclusive=false,extractor=,format=btree,huffman_key=,huffman_value=,ignore_in_memory_cache_size=false,immutable=false,internal_item_max=0,internal_key_max=0,internal_key_truncate=true,internal_page_max=4KB,key_format=q,key_gap=10,leaf_item_max=0,leaf_key_max=0,leaf_page_max=32KB,leaf_value_max=64MB,log=(enabled=true),lsm=(auto_throttle=true,bloom=true,bloom_bit_count=16,bloom_config=,bloom_hash_count=8,bloom_oldest=false,chunk_count_limit=0,chunk_max=5GB,chunk_size=10MB,merge_max=15,merge_min=0),memory_page_max=10m,os_cache_dirty_max=0,os_cache_max=0,prefix_compression=false,prefix_compression_min=4,source=,split_deepen_min_child=0,split_deepen_per_child=0,split_pct=90,type=file,value_format=u",
        "type": "file",
        "uri": "statistics:table:collection-5--7054136916324318927",
        "LSM": {
            "bloom filter false positives": 0,
            "bloom filter hits": 0,
            "bloom filter misses": 0,
            "bloom filter pages evicted from cache": 0,
            "bloom filter pages read into cache": 0,
            "bloom filters in the LSM tree": 0,
            "chunks in the LSM tree": 0,
            "highest merge generation in the LSM tree": 0,
            "queries that could have benefited from a Bloom filter that did not exist": 0,
            "sleep for LSM checkpoint throttle": 0,
            "sleep for LSM merge throttle": 0,
            "total size of bloom filters": 0
        },
        "block-manager": {
            "allocations requiring file extension": 0,
            "blocks allocated": 0,
            "blocks freed": 0,
            "checkpoint size": 16116039680,
            "file allocation unit size": 4096,
            "file bytes available for reuse": 679936,
            "file magic number": 120897,
            "file major version number": 1,
            "file size in bytes": 16116736000,
            "minor version number": 0
        },
        "btree": {
            "btree checkpoint generation": 8,
            "column-store fixed-size leaf pages": 0,
            "column-store internal pages": 0,
            "column-store variable-size RLE encoded values": 0,
            "column-store variable-size deleted values": 0,
            "column-store variable-size leaf pages": 0,
            "fixed-record size": 0,
            "maximum internal page key size": 368,
            "maximum internal page size": 4096,
            "maximum leaf page key size": 2867,
            "maximum leaf page size": 32768,
            "maximum leaf page value size": 67108864,
            "maximum tree depth": 5,
            "number of key/value pairs": 0,
            "overflow pages": 0,
            "pages rewritten by compaction": 0,
            "row-store internal pages": 0,
            "row-store leaf pages": 0
        },
        "cache": {
            "bytes currently in the cache": 12792138927,
            "bytes read into cache": 250345438600,
            "bytes written from cache": 0,
            "checkpoint blocked page eviction": 0,
            "data source pages selected for eviction unable to be evicted": 105,
            "hazard pointer blocked page eviction": 96,
            "in-memory page passed criteria to be split": 0,
            "in-memory page splits": 0,
            "internal pages evicted": 930,
            "internal pages split during eviction": 0,
            "leaf pages split during eviction": 0,
            "modified pages evicted": 0,
            "overflow pages read into cache": 0,
            "overflow values cached in memory": 0,
            "page split during eviction deepened the tree": 0,
            "page written requiring lookaside records": 0,
            "pages read into cache": 9082966,
            "pages read into cache requiring lookaside entries": 0,
            "pages requested from the cache": 199777277,
            "pages written from cache": 0,
            "pages written requiring in-memory restoration": 0,
            "tracked dirty bytes in the cache": 0,
            "unmodified pages evicted": 8620195
        },
        "cache_walk": {
            "Average difference between current eviction generation when the page was last considered": 0,
            "Average on-disk page image size seen": 0,
            "Clean pages currently in cache": 0,
            "Current eviction generation": 0,
            "Dirty pages currently in cache": 0,
            "Entries in the root page": 0,
            "Internal pages currently in cache": 0,
            "Leaf pages currently in cache": 0,
            "Maximum difference between current eviction generation when the page was last considered": 0,
            "Maximum page size seen": 0,
            "Minimum on-disk page image size seen": 0,
            "On-disk page image sizes smaller than a single allocation unit": 0,
            "Pages created in memory and never written": 0,
            "Pages currently queued for eviction": 0,
            "Pages that could not be queued for eviction": 0,
            "Refs skipped during cache traversal": 0,
            "Size of the root page": 0,
            "Total number of pages currently in cache": 0
        },
        "compression": {
            "compressed pages read": 9059006,
            "compressed pages written": 0,
            "page written failed to compress": 0,
            "page written was too small to compress": 0,
            "raw compression call failed, additional data available": 0,
            "raw compression call failed, no additional data available": 0,
            "raw compression call succeeded": 0
        },
        "cursor": {
            "bulk-loaded cursor-insert calls": 0,
            "create calls": 8,
            "cursor-insert key and value bytes inserted": 0,
            "cursor-remove key bytes removed": 0,
            "cursor-update value bytes updated": 0,
            "insert calls": 0,
            "next calls": 28302986,
            "prev calls": 1,
            "remove calls": 0,
            "reset calls": 1526364,
            "restarted searches": 0,
            "search calls": 85076270,
            "search near calls": 223128,
            "truncate calls": 0,
            "update calls": 0
        },
        "reconciliation": {
            "dictionary matches": 0,
            "fast-path pages deleted": 0,
            "internal page key bytes discarded using suffix compression": 0,
            "internal page multi-block writes": 0,
            "internal-page overflow keys": 0,
            "leaf page key bytes discarded using prefix compression": 0,
            "leaf page multi-block writes": 0,
            "leaf-page overflow keys": 0,
            "maximum blocks required for a page": 0,
            "overflow values written": 0,
            "page checksum matches": 0,
            "page reconciliation calls": 0,
            "page reconciliation calls for eviction": 0,
            "pages deleted": 0
        },
        "session": {
            "object compaction": 0,
            "open cursor count": 8
        },
        "transaction": {
            "update conflicts": 0
        }
    },
    "nindexes": 4,
    "totalIndexSize": 1292075008,
    "indexSizes": {
        "_id_": 297906176,
        "client.requestInTs_1": 301621248,
        "producer.requestInTs_1": 255086592,
        "producer.requestInTs_1_client.requestInTs_1": 437460992
    },
    "ok": 1
}
```

Here's an example document:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("59ebc4e84f413c70b03b50c2"),
    "clientResponseSize": null,
    "producerRequestSize": null,
    "producer": {
        "messageProtocolVersion":"string_here",
        "requestAttachmentCount":0,
        "serviceXRoadInstance":"string_here",
        "serviceMemberCode":"string_here",
        "representedPartyClass":null,
        "_id":ObjectId("59e6595d97b2ca507adc8383"),
        "responseMimeSize":1712,
        "serviceSecurityServerAddress":"string_here",
        "clientMemberClass":"string_here",
        "responseOutTs":NumberLong("1494334810378"),
        "soapFaultString":null,
        "representedPartyCode":null,
        "requestInTs":NumberLong("1494334807497"),
        "succeeded":true,
        "messageIssue":null,
        "requestOutTs":NumberLong("1494334808900"),
        "securityServerInternalIp":"string_here",
        "clientSecurityServerAddress":"string_here",
        "requestMimeSize":null,
        "serviceMemberClass":"string_here",
        "insertTime":1508268360.8759887,
        "requestSoapSize":1293,
        "responseSoapSize":1684,
        "clientMemberCode":"string_here",
        "serviceCode":"string_here",
        "messageId":"string_here",
        "clientXRoadInstance":"string_here",
        "monitoringDataTs":1494334810,
        "clientSubsystemCode":"string_here",
        "soapFaultCode":null,
        "responseAttachmentCount":1,
        "securityServerType":"string_here",
        "responseInTs":NumberLong("1494334808946"),
        "serviceSubsystemCode":"string_here",
        "messageUserId":"string_here",
        "serviceVersion":"string_here"
    },
    "producerIsDuration": null,
    "matchingType": "string_here",
    "requestNwDuration": null,
    "responseNwDuration": null,
    "client": {
        "messageProtocolVersion": "string_here",
        "requestAttachmentCount": null,
        "serviceXRoadInstance": "string_here",
        "serviceMemberCode": "string_here",
        "representedPartyClass": null,
        "_id": ObjectId("59e659a497b2ca50907e9a1a"),
        "responseMimeSize": null,
        "serviceSecurityServerAddress": "string_here",
        "clientMemberClass": "string_here",
        "responseOutTs": NumberLong("1494351723876"),
        "soapFaultString": "string_here",
        "representedPartyCode": null,
        "requestInTs": NumberLong("1494351723762"),
        "succeeded": false,
        "messageIssue": null,
        "requestOutTs": NumberLong("1494351723869"),
        "securityServerInternalIp": "string_here",
        "clientSecurityServerAddress": "string_here",
        "requestMimeSize": null,
        "serviceMemberClass": "string_here",
        "insertTime": 1508268421.6967819,
        "requestSoapSize": 1056,
        "responseSoapSize": null,
        "clientMemberCode": "string_here",
        "serviceCode": "string_here",
        "messageId": "string_here",
        "clientXRoadInstance": "string_here",
        "monitoringDataTs": 1494351723,
        "clientSubsystemCode": "string_here",
        "soapFaultCode": "string_here",
        "responseAttachmentCount": null,
        "securityServerType": "string_here",
        "responseInTs": null,
        "serviceSubsystemCode": "string_here",
        "messageUserId": "string_here",
        "serviceVersion": "string_here"
    },
    "producerSsRequestDuration": null,
    "producerDurationClientView": null,
    "correctorStatus": "done",
    "totalDuration": 114,
    "correctorTime": 1509006319.0692048,
    "clientRequestSize": 1056,
    "messageId": "string_here",
    "producerSsResponseDuration": null,
    "clientSsRequestDuration": 107,
    "producerDurationProducerView": null,
    "producerResponseSize": null,
    "producerHash": null,
    "clientSsResponseDuration": null,
    "clientHash": "string_here"
}
```

Can anyone explain why does the last query take so long?

Comment: Are `producer` and `client` array fields?

Comment: @JohnnyHK - No, they are timestamps of type Int64.

Comment: Could you please post the last command with the explain mode? `collection.find({"producer.requestInTs": {"$gte": start_time, "$lte": end_time}, "client.requestInTs": {"$gte": start_time, "$lte": end_time}}).explain()`

Comment: @JohnnyHK, rphonika - Edited the question with the results.

Comment: @EerikMuuli please also post the output of `db.collection.stats()` and an example document.

Comment: @JohnnyHK - Formatted & added more information.

Comment: @KevinAdistambha - Added output of the `db.collection.stats()` and an example document.